# iTunes App Screenshots

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I have an app that I am uploading to iTunes Connect, and I have loaded five hi-res iPhone 5 images (since it runs on iPhone 5). I know I have to also to have to load 640x960 images. However do I need to load 5, to be able to see 5 images on iTunes.

In [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html) Apple Developer document, they only have one image for iPhone 5. In that case would only one image load, or would it also load the other 640x960 images? Would it also work the other way around?

I am asking primarily because I only have an iPhone 5 to test it on, and the Simulator's graphics are even comparable and scaling the images makes them look odd.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, iTunes only loads the screenshots for the screen size of the device it is being used on. On the computer, i'm pretty sure it loads the 3.5".